# Jquery error in URL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I know we can call php script from jquery, with parameters, as given below.

```
$('.likelink').click(function() {
    $.get("testapache1.php", { dom: "<?php echo $_GET['dom']; ?>" , link: $(this).text() , pro: $(this).attr('name') }, function(resp) {
         alert(resp);
    });
});
```

I am getting error as given below on click event.

```
GET http://lsdom.qbc.uws/testapache1.php?dom=10.3.2.0&link=acer%0A&pro=acer 404 Not Found 4ms
```

I just want my link this

```
GET http://lsdom.qbc.uws/testapache1.php?dom=10.3.2.0&link=acer&pro=acer
```

What could be the error in my jquery script ? Please help me.

Comment: Are you sure that http://lsdom.qbc.uws/testapache1.php exists?

Comment: @ChrisC you opened my eyes.There was a spelling mistake in my URL.is there anyway to delete this post ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a new line character in your `link` object, which gets encoded as `%0A` (link=acer%0A).

Comment: Thanks bro for quick reply.It was my mistake in giving proper URL

Answer (score 0):

If you just wont to pass the data don't use separate java script function.It's way more complected.

you can do as folow,

```
<a href="lsdom.qbc.uws/testapache1.php?dom=<?php echo $_GET['dom'];>

&link=<?php echo $GET['you'r variable'] ?>&pro=<?php echo $_GET['your variable']?>></a>
```

(make sure you add a form to you'r page & set it action as GET